# ¿Cómo puedo obtener imágenes que tengo alojadas en un servidor Express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Tengo un problema al momento de acceder a una imagen que guardo en el servidor.

```
app.use('/sources', express.static(__dirname + 'src/images'))
```

Defino la ruta, pero al acceder a alguna imagen de source, siempre me manda un error de Cannot GET[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La jerarquía de los archivos la tengo de la siguiente manera, y la carpeta src está al nivel de app.js que es donde defino la ruta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo de esta manera:

```
const staticRoute = path.join(__dirname, '/src/images')

app.use('/sources', express.static(staticRoute))
```

te falto un `/` antes de src, y es mejor usar `path.join` en un lugar de concatenar con `+` ya que `path.join` une las rutas que le pases como argumentos y te normaliza/resuelve a rutas dependiendo tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, me dí cuenta que el error era por la jerarquía de las carpetas.